# boost::binary_iarchive instead of boost::text_iarchive from SQLite3 Blob

Tags: c++, iostream, boost-serialization

I'm not an expert on streams and buffers, though I have learned an immense amount over the last month since I started tackling this problem.

This concerns boost::serialization and if I can get the binary archiving working, I'll save 50% of the storage space.

I've searched all over StackOverflow for the answer, and I've pieced together the following code that works, but only for text_iarchive. If I try to move to binary_iarchive, I get a segment fault with a message of "boost serialize allocate(size_t n) 'n' exceeds maximum supported size" or any other number of errors where it is obvious that there is a disconnect between the input stream/buffer and what binary_iarchive is expecting.

Like I said earlier, this works perfectly with text_iarchive. I can text_oarchive to an SQLite3 Blob, verify it in the database, retrieve it, text_iarchive it back in to the complex object, and it works perfectly.

Is there something wrong with the way I set up the input stream and buffer?

To not confuse everyone, I am NOT posting the structure of the object I am serializing and deserializing. There are many `vector<double>`, an Eigen Matrix, and a couple of basic objects. They work perfectly and are not part of the problem! (And yes, I delete the database records between tests to guard against reading a text_oarchive into a binary_iarchive.)

Here is the output archive section. This appears to work perfectly for text_oarchive OR binary_oarchive. The Blob shows up in the database and appears to be of the proper binary structure.

```
// BinaryData is a Typedef for std::vector<char>
   BinaryData serializedDataStream;
   bio::stream<bio::back_insert_device<BinaryData>> outbuf {serializedDataStream};

// I change the text_oarchive to binary_oarchive and uncomment the std::ios::binary parameter.
// when I'm attempting to move from text to binary

   boost::archive::text_oarchive outStream(outbuf); //, std::ios::binary);
             outStream << ssInputDataAndBestModel_->theModel_;
             outbuf.flush();
             // have to convert to unsigned char since that is the way sqlite3 expects to see
             // a Blob object type
             std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(serializedDataStream.begin(),serializedDataStream.end());

I then pass "buffer" to the SQLite3 processing object to store it in the Blob.
```

Here is the input archive section. The Blobs look identical storing and then retreiving from the DB whether it's text or binary. (But a text doesn't look like a binary, obviously.)

```
// this line is to get the blob out of SQLite3
currentModelDBRecPtr = cpp17::any_cast<dbo::ptr<Model>>(modelListModel);
        if (!currentModelDBRecPtr->theModel.empty()) {
            
            // have to convert to char since that is the way boost::serialize expects to see
            // an archived object type (blob is vector of unsigned char)
            std::vector<char> blobBuffer(currentModelDBRecPtr->theModel.begin(), currentModelDBRecPtr->theModel.end());
            boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> membuf(blobBuffer.data(), blobBuffer.size());

            std::istream &input_stream = membuf;

// Note: I change the following to binary_iarchive and uncomment the 
// std::ios::binary flag to try to move from text_iarchive to binary_iarchive
            boost::archive::text_iarchive input_archive(input_stream); //, std::ios::binary);
            TheModel inputArchiveModel;

// it crashes on the next line, but it DOES successfully recreate half
// of the object before it randomly crashes. 
             input_archive >> inputArchiveModel;

        }
```